# Form not redirect to the process file. PHP

Tags: html

I have a problem here. The form not redirect to the process file after I click the button.

This is the form code :

```
<form action="add_testimonial.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="nama">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" style="margin-top: 10px;" name="email">
    <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px;" name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" style="margin-top: 10px;" name="foto_profil">
    <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="button" value="Send testimonial"  name="finish" style="margin-top: 10px;">
</form>
```

Hope anyone can help my problem.

Comment: change input type button to submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change input type button to submit

```
<form action="add_testimonial.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="nama">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" style="margin-top: 10px;" name="email">
    <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px;" name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" style="margin-top: 10px;" name="foto_profil">
    <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Send testimonial"  name="finish" style="margin-top: 10px;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The last button should have the following type:

```
<input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Send testimonial"  name="finish" style="margin-top: 10px;">
```

Type `submit` garantee that you send the form data to the `action` page. Here are [a few explanations](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/submit) from the Mozilla Team.

Answer (score 0):

Change your input type "button" to "submit"

```
<input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Send testimonial"  name="finish" style="margin-top: 10px;">
```